# Python: Check if data file exists relative to source code file

Tags: python, file

I have a small text (XML) file that I want a Python function to load. The location of the text file is always in a fixed relative position to the Python function code.

For example, on my local computer, the files text.xml and mycode.py could reside in:

```
/a/b/text.xml
/a/c/mycode.py
```

Later at run time, the files could reside in:

```
/mnt/x/b/text.xml
/mnt/x/c/mycode.py
```

How do I ensure I can load in the file? Do I need the absolute path? I see that I can use os.path.isfile, but that presumes I have a path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do a call as follows:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

This will get you the directory of the python file you're calling from `mycode.py`

then accessing the xml files is as simple as:

```
xml_file = "{}/../text.xml".format(BASE_DIR)
fin = open(xml_file, 'r+')
```

Answer (score 1):

If the parent directory of the two directories are always the same this should work:

```
import os
path_to_script = os.path.realpath(__file__)
parent_directory = os.path.dirname(path_to_script)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(parent_directory):
    for file in files:
        if file == 'text.xml':
            path_to_xml = os.path.join(root, file)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the special variable `__file__` which gives you the current file name (see http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html).

So in your first example, you can reference text.xml this way in mycode.py:

```
xml_path = os.path.join(__file__, '..', '..', 'text.xml')
```

Comment: But `__file__` returns the directory as well as the script file's name! Something like `C:\path\to\script\myscript.py\..\..\text.xml`... which I think requires further processing.